# Ansible playbook error in Roles vars section while copying the main.yaml file of vars from a remote machine

Tags: yaml, jinja2, ansible

[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yq4.png)I am trying to execute a ansible playbook using roles. I have some variables, which I defined in main.yaml of vars section. I am copying these variables (main.yaml) from another remote machine.
My question is, my playbook throws an error for the first time even though it copies the main.yaml file in my vars section. When I run for second time, it executes playbook well. I am understanding, for the first time though the file is copied it doesn't read it as it was not present before the playbook was running. Is there a way I can run it successfully without an error for the first time.

Image roles will give clear idea about roles and sub files. [Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUifw.png)

**site.yaml**

```
---
- name: Testing the Mini project
  hosts: all
  roles:
  - test
```

**tasks/main.yaml**

```
---
- name: Converting Mysql to CSV file
  command: mysqldump -u root -padmin -T/tmp charan test --fields-terminated-by=,
  when: inventory_hostname == "ravi"

- name: Converting CSV file to yaml format
  shell: python /tmp/test.py > /tmp/main.yaml
  when: inventory_hostname == "ravi"

- name:Copying yaml file from remote node to vars
  shell: sshpass -p admin scp -r root@192.168.56.101:/tmp/main.yaml /etc/ansible/Test/roles/vars/main.yaml
  when: inventory_hostname == "charan"

- name:Install Application as per the table
  apt: name={{ item.Application }} state=present
  when: inventory_hostname == {{ item.Username }} 
  with_items: user_app
```

**/vars/main.yaml** This will be copied from remote machine.

```
---
user_app:
- {Username: '"ravi"' , Application: curl}
- {Username: '"charan"' , Application: git}
```

Comment: Could you pleas show us your playbook (especially the task the error is thrown)

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the error message, please check that.

Comment: We really need to see the relevant parts of your playbook to see precisely what you're doing.  The stack trace alone isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [include_vars task](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html).  It may do what you need.  It looks like you need to be explicitly including `/vars/main.yaml` in a task before your apt task where you reference the variables.

Comment: Hi Bruce, I have done that as well, using include, still for the first time it is not executing the commands. When I run the play-book second time the changes are taking place.